# Wire up button created at runtime

Tags: asp.net

Im creating some buttons based on a value of some runtime variable (i dont even know how many).

My code for the button is as follows:

```
Button cancel = new Button();
            cancel.Text = "Cancel";
            cancel.ID = "cancelEnrollmentForStudent" + zapsanePredmetyList.ElementAt(i).ID.ToString() + "-" + i ;
            cancel.Click += new EventHandler(cancelEnrollment);
            string toCancel = selectedSubject.SelectedValue + ";" + studentToEnroll.SelectedValue;
            cancel.CommandArgument = toCancel;
```

while the code for the click method is

```
protected void cancelEnrollment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something when button clicked. 
        Button sourceButton = (Button)sender;
        string[] data = sourceButton.CommandArgument.Split(';');
    }
```

However, the click method is not firing up when the button is clicked. I suppose this has something to do with the fact, that I build the button at runtime. Cld someone advise on how to get this method fire up?

Thanks,
Ondrej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override OnInit add the code in OnInit method.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) 
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "btn1";
    btn.Text = "Button1";   
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    this.form1.Controls.Add(btn);
}

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    Button bt = (Button)sender;
    bt.Text = "Changed";        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But seems I'm doing something wrong - when I add the override code to the page, it causes compilation problems for other server-side form elements and thus the code fails to compile.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.subjects_choosesubject_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'studentToEnroll_DataBound' and no extension method 'studentToEnroll_DataBound' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.subjects_choosesubject_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I just copy-pasted your code, but changed the oninit to call not btn_click but my own method o the only difference is btn.Click += new EventHandler(cancelEnrollment);

Comment: Check if this studentToEnroll_DataBound exists in your code file, if yes what argument it has. For testing dynamic control addition and event binding you can make a new page to test and later modify your desired page

Comment: I suppose it does exist somewhere but I didnt create it manually - its a visually-added dropdownlist with visually configured LinqToSQL datasource. Do I need to manually rewrite this into the code?

Comment: Yes, you can also undo the code to get to the position where it work working fine